# FFMPEG's seek can't convert decimal to sexagesimal accurately

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg i- "file.mp4" -ss 0.03334
```

should seek to the third frame

```
0.03334 * 60 = 2.0004
```

(first frame is 0, second frame is 1, third frame is 2...)

but it's actually seeking to the second frame.

any idea how to fix this? thank you

Comment: From the documentation: When used as an input option (before -i), seeks in this input file to position. *Note that in most formats it is not possible to seek exactly*, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before position.

Comment: I'm not using it before -i (as shown above)

Comment: Show full command and log.